# Display all columns where instances of case_num column > 1 and ordering by amount desc per case_num

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of invoices that I would like to display the records where there is more than 1 instance of [case_num], ordering by usd_amt descending, but keeping the case_num records together.

The first record should be the highest usd_amt, followed by all records with the same case_num (displayed usd_amt DESC), the next record should be the next highest usd_amt, followed by all records with the same case_num (displayed usd_amt DESC) and so on

sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoices](
    [invoice_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [case_num] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [usd_amt] [float] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [invoice_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Invoices]
    ([invoice_id]
    ,[case_num]
    ,[usd_amt])
VALUES
    (39341598,  '1.83722e+009|o|126547',  79752.6621),
    (40951156,  '1.83722e+009|o|126547',  79194.0256),
    (41809870,  '1.83722e+009|o|126547',  79190.6121),
    (42002432,  '3090|o|19319', 3090.00),
    (39540302,  '3090|o|19319', 3090.00),
    (41182508,  '3090|o|19319',  120.00),
    (42825471,  '13959|o|8986',  130.95),
    (42825546,  '13959|o|8986',  130.95),
    (42959088,  '10274|o|8986',  96.64);
```

Desired Output:

```
invoice_id  case_num                usd_amt
39341598    1.83722e+009|o|126547   79752.6621
40951156    1.83722e+009|o|126547   79194.0256
41809870    1.83722e+009|o|126547   79190.6121
42002432    3090|o|19319            3090
39540302    3090|o|19319            3090
41182508    3090|o|19319            120
42825471    13959|o|8986            130.95
42825546    13959|o|8986            130.95
```

after reading some other SO pages I think I need some combination of using ROW_NUMBER() partitioning by the case_num and assigning an ordinal, or using a CTE, but I'm currently stuck. 
Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Then show us what you tried and why it didn't work; otherwise this is just a duplicate of the many examples already out there.

Comment: No it doesn't, I don't want top (1) of each, I need to display the records with more than 1 instance of case_num ordering by usd_amt desc per case_num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a window count over `case_num` partitions in a suquery (or CTE) and then use it for filering. For ordering, you can use a window max.

```
select invoice_id, case_num, usd_amt
from (select t.*, count(*) over(partition by case_num) cnt from [dbo].[Invoices] t) t
where cnt > 1
order by max(usd_amt) over(partition by case_num) desc, usd_amt desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=19a4dd10cbd112e6569f3f289136c2a0)**:

```
invoice_id | case_num              |    usd_amt
---------: | :-------------------- | ---------:
  39341598 | 1.83722e+009|o|126547 | 79752.6621
  40951156 | 1.83722e+009|o|126547 | 79194.0256
  41809870 | 1.83722e+009|o|126547 | 79190.6121
  42002432 | 3090|o|19319          |       3090
  39540302 | 3090|o|19319          |       3090
  41182508 | 3090|o|19319          |        120
  42825471 | 13959|o|8986          |     130.95
  42825546 | 13959|o|8986          |     130.95
```

Comment: close but look at the desired output. the first record should be the highest usd_amt, followed by all records with the same case_num (displayed usd_amt DESC), the next record should be the next highest usd_amt, followed by all records with the same case_num (displayed usd_amt DESC) and so on.

Comment: @Jdub: that was not obvious at all in your question... You order with a window max, I edited my answer.

Comment: updated the question with that description, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yoiu can use a CTE and a windowed `COUNT`, and then return rows where the count is greater than 1:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT invoice_id,
           case_num,
           usd_amt,
           COUNT(invoice_id) OVER (PARTITION BY case_num) AS Invoices,
           MAX(usd_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY case_num) AS Max_usd
    FROM dbo.Invoices)
SELECT invoice_id,
       case_num,
       usd_amt
FROM CTE
WHERE Invoices > 1
ORDER BY Max_usd DESC,
         usd_amt DESC;
```

Comment: close but case_num '3090|o|19319' records should be displayed above '13959|o|8986' records

Comment: So it should be `case_num DESC`, @Jbub ? The order by your data, for `case_num` makes little less, as `'1'` is less than `'3'`, but you have it at the start and end of your data. `'1.83722e+009|o|126547'` is not a number, and it dose not order like one. `'1.83722e+009|o|126547'` is **less** than `'3090|o|19319'`. If you want those values to order like nunmbers, you need to fix the design and not store delimited data.

Comment: no, look at the desired output. the first record should be the highest usd_amt, followed by all records with the same case_num (displayed usd_amt DESC), the next record should be the next highest usd_amt, followed by all records with the same case_num (displayed usd_amt DESC) and so on..

Comment: Then you should describe that, @Jdub . "*ordering by usd_amt desc per case_num"* dosen't suggest that at all. It suggests to order the data in descending order by `Case_num` not order the `case_num`'s by their maximum values of `usd_amt` descending, and then by `usd_amt` descending